# How to integrate webix in quasar

Tags: quasar, webix

I use webix in some laravel applications. Now, i like to give a try to quasar.dev
But quaser doesn't has an index file in dev mode.
How can I implement webix completely to quasar from a local file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to include webix.js through the Quasar Boot config
Check https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files#Introduction

You can add something like

```
import * as webix from "webix";
```

or

```
import * as webix from "@xbs/webix-pro";
```

at top of the boot file